# Insert multiple sObjects in single DML call

Tags: apex, custom-object, dml

I have 3 objects. Account, Contact and AccountContact(custom).

When I try to insert account and contact using one insert statement as follows, it works perfectly

```
Account a = new Account(Customer_ID__c='12345',name='accounttest');
Contact c = new Contact(account=new Account(Customer_ID__c='12345'),lastname = 'test', externalId__c='extId');

insert new List<sObject>{a, c};
```

Now, I am trying to insert custom object(Accountcontact) which has lookup to contact as follows:

```
Account a = new Account(Customer_ID__c='12345',name='accounttest');
Contact c = new Contact(account=new Account(Customer_ID__c='12345'),lastname = 'test', externalId__c='extId');
AccountContact__c ac = new AccountContact__c(name='testing', Contact__c = new Contact(externalId__c='extId'));

insert new List<sObject>{a, c, ac};
```

Above code throws an error "`Invalid initial expression type for field AccountContact__c.Contact__c, expecting: Id`"

Is there a way to achieve inserting all 3 in single DML call. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use a related field Contact__r to associate the Contact to AccountContact__c.

Try below code,

```
List<sObject> records = new List<sObject>();
records.add(new Account(AccountExternalId__c='1234555', Name='ABCD Company'));

records.add(new Contact(account=new Account(AccountExternalId__c='1234555'),lastname = 'Testlast', ContactExternalId__c='3525'));

records.add(new AccountContact__c (Contact__r = new Contact(ContactExternalId__c='3525')));

insert records;
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to use the name pointing reference. Here, that would be `Contact__r`.

It might be more clear if you look at how it works if you set the value dynamically: you can either call `set` with the Id, or `setSObject` with the record.

```
AccountContact__c junction = new AccountContact__c();
junction.set('Contact__c', someContactId);
//OR
junction.setSObject('Contact__r', someContactRecord);
```

Also, note that you can always get the name of this relationship through the describe.

```
DescribeFieldResult describe = AccountContact__c.Contact__c.getDescribe();
system.debug(describe.getRelationshipName());
```

In your working case, the field has an `API Name` of `AccountId`, and a `Relationship Name` of `Account`. What you're trying to do in the junction object is analogous to if you modified your working snippet as follows:

```
Contact record = new Contact(AccountId=new Account(...));
```